# Weierstrass M test: What can used as $M_n$ for $\frac {|\log(n)|}{n^x}$ if $x>1$

Tags: real-analysis

I said that since $M_n$ cant depend on $x$,  $\frac {|\log(n)|}{n^x} \leq \frac{\log(n)}{n^{\delta+1}}$ where  $x \geq \delta+1$  But i don't if this is correct and if the infinite series of $\frac{\log(n)}{n^{\delta+1}}$ converges.

Comment: It is correct because $e^x$ increases. The series converges by comparison with the integral $\int_1^A t^{-(1 + \delta)}\log t d t$.